# ansible task inside task

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-facts

I am looking for way to run task inside an another task

```
  - name: Get object facts
    checkpoint_policy_pkg_facts:
    register: results

  - name: "set fact for policy pkg selection"
    set_fact:
      pkges: "{{ results  | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
       query: "ansible_facts.checkpoint_access_layers.packages[].name"

  - name: Get object facts
    checkpoint_policy_pkg_facts:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    register: results
    with_items: "{{ pkges }}"

  - name: "set fact for policy pkg selection"
    set_fact:
      pkgname: "{{ results  | json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
       query: "results[?ansible_facts.checkpoint_access_layers.\"installation-targets-revision\"[?\"cluster-members-revision\"[?\"target-name\"=='{{ item }}']]].item | [0]"
    with_items: "{{ targets }}"
```

output will be like below

```
           "PolicyPKG1",
            "PolicyPKG2",
            "Standard"
```

i wanted insert the pkgname to another task one by one using the below task, since my target item is huge i wanted to inert the corresponding pkgname to servicenow using the below task

```
  - name: Create a change request
    snow_record:
      state: present
      table: u_device
      username: admin
      password: 
      instance: dev778899
      data:
        u_name:  "{{ pkgname }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register the `pkgname` as variable and use `pkgname.stdout_lines` as variable later,

```
 - name: "set fact for policy pkg selection"
   register: pkgname
   vars:
   query: "results[?ansible_facts.checkpoint_access_layers.\"installation-targets-revision\"[?\"cluster-members-revision\"[?\"target-name\"=='{{ item }}']]].item | [0]"
   with_items: "{{ targets }}"
```

And next:

```
 - name: Create a change request
   snow_record:
     state: present
     table: u_device
     username: admin
     password: 
     instance: dev778899
     data:
       u_name:  "{{ item }}"
   with_items: "{{ pkgname.stdout_lines }}"
```